# Sql Server Insert into with lookup tables with stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL Server and I would like to ask something about inserting and updating data.
I want to create stored procedures for my Select - Insert - Delete - Update.

I am using ASP.NET for my application.

First of all let me give you my database schema. I am working in SQL Server 2008

I have 4 tables -

```
tbl_Equipment   |  tbl_Location  |  tbl_Condition  | tbl_Category
```

`tbl_Equipment`:

- equip_ID  ***int  (PK - identity)***
- Product   *nvarchar(50)*
- AquiredDate *datetime*
- SerialNumber *nvarchar(50)*
- PurchasedPlace *nvarchar(50)*
- Manufacturer *nvarchar(50)*
- Model *nvarchar(50)*
- Comments *nvarchar(500)*
- categ_ID **int(FK - tbl_Category)**
- cond_ID  ***int(FK -tbl_Condition)***
- loc_ID ***int(FK - tbl_Location)***

`tbl_Category`:

- categ_ID *int   (PK - identify)*
- Category *nvarchar(50)*

`tbl_Condition`:

- cond_ID  *int  (PK - identify)*
- Condition *nvarchar(50)*

`tbl_Location`:

- loc_ID  *int   (PK - identify)*
- Location *nvarchar(50)*

Tables `Condition`, `Location` and `Category` are lookup tables.

I want to insert values into table `Equipment` and to choose from a dropdown list from the lookup tables and update my data.

A small approach that I tried :

My Select

```
 SELECT  
    tbl_Equipment.Product,      
    tbl_Equipment.AquiredDate, 
tbl_Equipment.SerialNumber,          
    tbl_Equipment.PurchasedPlace, 
tbl_Equipment.Manufacturer,         
    tbl_Equipment.Model, 
tbl_Equipment.Comments,         
    tbl_Condition.Condition,
tbl_Category.Category,          
    tbl_Location.Location
FROM    
    tbl_Category 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Equipment ON tbl_Category.categ_ID = tbl_Equipment.categ_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Condition ON tbl_Equipment.cond_ID = tbl_Condition.cond_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Location ON tbl_Equipment.loc_ID = tbl_Location.loc_ID>
```

My Insert

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertEquipTable
    @Product nvarchar(50),
    @AquiredDate datetime,
    @SerialNumber nvarchar(20),
    @PurchasedPlace nvarchar(50),
    @Insured nvarchar(10),
    @Manufacturer nvarchar(50),
    @Model nvarchar(50),
    @Comments nvarchar(50),
    @categ_ID int,
    @cond_ID int,
    @loc_ID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
       tbl_Equipment.Product,
       tbl_Equipment.AquiredDate,
       tbl_Equipment.SerialNumber,  
       tbl_Equipment.PurchasedPlace,
       tbl_Equipment.Insured,
       tbl_Equipment.Manufacturer,
       tbl_Equipment.Model, 
       tbl_Equipment.Comments,
       tbl_Category.Category,
       tbl_Condition.Condition,
       tbl_Location.Location, 
       tbl_Equipment.categ_ID,
       tbl_Equipment.cond_ID,
       tbl_Equipment.loc_ID
    FROM        
       tbl_Category 
    INNER JOIN
       tbl_Equipment ON tbl_Category.categ_ID = tbl_Equipment.categ_ID 
    INNER JOIN
       tbl_Condition ON tbl_Equipment.cond_ID = tbl_Condition.cond_ID 
    INNER JOIN
       tbl_Location ON tbl_Equipment.loc_ID = tbl_Location.loc_ID

    INSERT INTO tbl_Equipment(Product, AquiredDate, SerialNumber, PurchasedPlace, Insured, 
                              Manufacturer, Model, Comments, categ_ID, cond_ID, loc_ID)
    VALUES(@Product, @AquiredDate, @SerialNumber, @PurchasedPlace, @Insured, 
           @Manufacturer, @Model, @Comments, @categ_ID, @cond_ID, @loc_ID)
END
```

Any help would be appreciated. Or if there is another approach for my problem, like enums etc .

Thank you for your time, and sorry for my bad code type.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `SELECT` in your stored procedure? It doesn't do anything. What's your actual issue?

Comment: Did you user choose the values for the FK from a DropDownList filled with the lookup table values?

Comment: [ElectricLiama] - I am using a SqlDataSource from my ASP.NET application to connect to the database and there are 4 tables that i have to manipulate it needs to be a custom SQL statement or stored procedure. My application needs to insert data from the user. Therefore must be a Select - Insert - Update and Delete StoredProcedure. My goal is to have 4 DropDownLists from my lookup tables and textboxes for my rest form.